# How to evaluate the volume of area $\{(x, y,z) | x^2 + zy^2 ≤ |z|, −1 ≤ y ≤ 1, −1 ≤ z ≤ 1\}$ in coordinate space?

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the volume of area$$\{(x, y,z) | x^2 + zy^2 ≤ |z|, −1 ≤ y ≤ 1, −1 ≤ z ≤ 1\}$$ in coordinate space.

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1 + t^2} dt =\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt2 + \ln(1 +\sqrt2))$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$S=\{(x, y,z)\; |\; |x|\leq f(x,y), −1 \leq y \leq 1, −1 \leq z \leq 1\}$$
where $|x|\leq f(y,z)$. Where $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|z|-zy^2}$.
Hence
$$\mbox{Volume}(S)=2\int_{z=-1}^1\int_{y=-1}^1f(y,z) dydz.$$
Note that
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1-y^2} \mbox{for $z\in[0,1]$},\quad
f(x,y)=\sqrt{|z|}\sqrt{1+y^2} \mbox{for $z\in[-1,0]$}.$$
Hence
$$\mbox{Volume}(S)=4\int_{z=0}^1\sqrt{z} dz\int_{y=0}^1\sqrt{1-y^2}dy
+4\int_{z=-1}^0\sqrt{|z|} dz\int_{y=0}^1\sqrt{1+y^2}dy.$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. The final result should be $\frac{2}{3}(\pi+2\sqrt{2}+2\ln(1+\sqrt{2}))$.

Comment: $2(pi/6 + 1/3(sqrt 2 +ln(1+sqrt2)))$

Comment: @user366725 I think that your result should be multiplied by $2$.